# VB.NET Compare dates, days, weeks to build new datetime variable

Tags: vb.net

Language: VB.NET or C# please!

I'm trying to apply a rule to determine a specific date and failing miserably.

Customer chooses a day (radio button): Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun.

I need to build a SendOnDate DateTime variable that is based upon what day was chosen and compare it to the current date.  Applying these basic rules:

1. If current date's day is <= date of day chosen, then use this weeks date for the day chosen (radio button).
2. If the current date's day is > date of day chosen, then use next weeks date for the day chosen(radio button).

I'm still very confused how to approach this and likely not describing things well.  Here's an attempt to setup some examples:

Scenario #1:
-(radio button) value = Thursday
-Current Date = 8/17/2015 (Monday)
-SendOnDate should be: 8/20/2015 (Thursday of the current date's week)

Scenario #2:
-(radio button) value = Monday
-Current Date = 8/19/2015 (Wednesday)
-SendOnDate should be: 8/24/2015 (Monday of the current date's following week)

Scenario #3:
-(radio button) value = Wednesday
-Current Date = 8/19/2015 (Wednesday)
-SendOnDate should be: 8/19/2015 (Wednesday of the current date's week)

I'm not exactly sure how to best approach this and set my SendOnDate value.

Comment: It doesnt matter which week it is in, does it?  In either case you want to pick the next Sun or Fri or whatever.  As long as it is a future date (tomorrow+) then that is the date.

Comment: It does matter which week!  I need to build this "SendOnDate" Date value based upon the logic applied above.  I'm probably not explaining very well.  If the day of the current date has not yet occurred in the current date's week, then build the SendOnDate value = to the day chosen for this week.  If the day of the current date has already occurred during the week, then use next week's day chosen.

Comment: At least with the basic DateTime Type you cant *tell* which week it is in, so you are confusing yourself with that rule.  In all cases you want to use today (S#3) or the date of the next selected day (S#1,2).  A For N loop stepping thru today and the next 6 days will find the next matching date (with an Exit For when it matches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing yourself with the aspect of *week*; in all cases mentioned either today or one of the following 6 days will match.

```
Private Function GetNextDay(dow As DayOfWeek) As DateTime
    Dim dtRet As DateTime = DateTime.Now

    ' one of today or next 6 days will match
    For n As Integer = 0 To 6
        dtRet = DateTime.Now.AddDays(n)
        If dtRet.DayOfWeek = dow Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Return dtRet
End Function
```

Test:

```
Console.WriteLine("Today is {0}", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString)
Dim pickedDay = DayOfWeek.Sunday
Console.WriteLine("For {0}, the schedule is {1}", pickedDay.ToString,
                  GetNextDay(pickedDay).ToShortDateString)

pickedDay = DayOfWeek.Wednesday
Console.WriteLine("For {0}, the schedule is {1}", pickedDay.ToString,
                  GetNextDay(pickedDay).ToShortDateString)

pickedDay = DayOfWeek.Saturday
Console.WriteLine("For {0}, the schedule is {1}", pickedDay.ToString,
                  GetNextDay(pickedDay).ToShortDateString)
```

Output:

> Today is 8/23/2015
>   For Sunday, the schedule is 8/23/2015
>   For Wednesday, the schedule is 8/26/2015
>   For Saturday, the schedule is 8/29/2015

The first satisfies Scenario 1 where today is eligible, the other 2 are just picking the coming `Date` where the `DayOfWeek` matches.  In cases where certain days like holidays are off limits, you's have to build a list of those and skip ahead a day or week.

Note: `GetNextDay` returns a `DateTime` variable, the code just doesnt capture it to a variable.

Comment: ahhhhh.... thank you for giving me something to see.  I will try and implement this asap!